Python CFFI module "not found" despite it being installed and upgraded to latest
I am trying to install python camellia (https://pypi.org/project/python-camellia/) and am getting this as an error:
[...]\Temp\pip-install-k55xzoj1\python-camellia_f66ad56a78554286b3a99832c02cbd94\src\camellia_build\_build_utils.py", line 8, in <module>
          from cffi import FFI
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cffi'
      [end of output]

I, obviously, first of all went and tried to install CFFI, was already there (I knew that) so no surprises.
pip3 install cffi
I then tried to upgraded (did need an upgrade) so I tried again after.
pip3 install --upgrade cffi
No dice, same result. I am heavily confused as to why this is since camellia is such an old module used in a couple of repos I know of, this is my personal first try at using it but a friend of mine has no issues with it...

Hi there, please have you upgraded not pip, and your OS e.g Linux?

Both pip and my OS are up to date, yes.
